# how to set Hadoop DistributedCache?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-cache

when I run the hadoop code to add the third jar,just like the following code:

```
public static void addTmpJar(String jarPath, JobConf conf) throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("path.separator", ":");
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);
    String newJarPath = new Path(jarPath).makeQualified(fs).toString();
    String tmpjars = conf.get("tmpjars");
    if (tmpjars == null || tmpjars.length() == 0) {
        conf.set("tmpjars", newJarPath);
    } else {
        conf.set("tmpjars", tmpjars + "," + newJarPath);
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Error initializing attempt_201405281453_0053_m_000002_0:
```

org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for taskTracker/hadoop/distcache/-7315515059647727905_-860888033_1107570546/nn.hadoop.dev/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/staging/hadoop/.staging/job_201405281453_0053/libjars/mahout-core-0.8-job.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager.getLocalCache(TrackerDistributedCacheManager.java:173)
    at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.TaskDistributedCacheManager.setupCache(TaskDistributedCacheManager.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$4.run(TaskTracker.java:1320)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$5.run(TaskTracker.java:2603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

any one who can tell how to solve this problem,thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the commandline you can add a jar to the distributedcache using `-libjars`, the only prerequisite is that your MR program implements Tool which uses GenericOptionsParser, the latter takes care of adding the jar to the cache.

[This page explains the above in more detail](http://grepalex.com/2013/02/25/hadoop-libjars/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,But I think that there is some hadoop configuration not suitable,because,I can run the code for three times in my hadoop cluster,but the when I run the fourth time , it caused the exception messages like above.